# javascript - How can I extend native DocumentFragment class?

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to append my DomBuilder to html by HTMLElement#appendChild.
And replace by jQuery#html

---

I tried this

```
var Fragment = function() {
};


Fragment.prototype = Object.create(DocumentFragment.prototype);
Fragment.prototype.append = function(el) {
    if (el instanceof DomBuilder) {
        return this.append(el.build());
    }

    if (el instanceof Element) {
        this.appendChild.(el);
    }

    return this;
};

$dom.frag = function() {
    var f = new Fragment();

    return f;
};
```

but

```
$dom.frag().append(document.createElement('a'))
```

throws 'Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation'.
I need super object (DocuemtnFragment) to do this.

Second try:

```
$dom.frag = function() {
    var f = document.createDocumentFragment();
    f.append = function(el) {
        if (el instanceof DomBuilder) {
            return this.append(el.build());
        }

        if (el instanceof Element) {
            this.appendChild(el);
        }

        return this;
    };
    return f;
};
```

works properly, but this will create function 'append' for every $dom.frag() call.

Third try:

```
DocumentFragment.prototype.append = function(el) {
    if (el instanceof DomBuilder) {
        return this.append(el.build());
    }

    if (el instanceof Element) {
        this.appendChild(el);
    }

    return this;
};


$dom.frag = function() {
    var f = document.createDocumentFragment();
    return f;
};
```

This works properly, and share function 'append'.
But is this ok? No cross-browser issue?

this site will support ie9~ / other modern browsers

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? jQuery uses fragments internally so there's no need to reinvent the wheel. If you're not going to use jQuery, just use appendChild to add to the fragment ?

Comment: @adeneo It's my dom manipullation library. I prefer using pure javascript if site need to be responsive, and must support android.

Comment: Then the last one is OK, it prototypes the append method to all fragments.

Comment: @adeneo Thank you. I can now save time to google.